# Django 1.9: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to use this app https://github.com/benliles/django-chance in my application. My Django version is 1.9. I am getting the following error:

```
python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f4931ce85f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/Event-Management-System/chance/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chance import signals
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/Event-Management-System/chance/signals.py", line 7, in <module>
    from chance.models import Registration
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/Event-Management-System/chance/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/ems/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

The file tree of website:-

```
├── chance
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_add_eventchoice_allow_multiple.py
│   │   ├── 0002_add_eventchoice_allow_multiple.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_add_created_and_label.py
│   │   ├── 0004_add_registration_owner.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── signals.py
│   ├── signals.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── chance
│   │       ├── event_detail.html
│   │       ├── event_list.html
│   │       ├── registration_email_manager_subject.txt
│   │       ├── registration_email_subject.txt
│   │       ├── registration_email.txt
│   │       └── registration_form.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── EMS
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── profile_images
│       ├── 20140810_175920.jpg
│       ├── IMG-20150215-WA0013.jpg
│       ├── IMG-20150215-WA0015.jpg
│       ├── IMG-20150215-WA0018-1.jpg
│       ├── IMG-20150304-WA0005.jpg
│       └── Shubham_20140216_234708-1.jpg
├── notifications
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── apps.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── signals.py
│   ├── signals.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   └── notifications
│   │       └── notify.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── notifications
│   │       ├── list.html
│   │       ├── notice.html
│   │       └── test_tags.html
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── notifications_tags.py
│   │   └── notifications_tags.pyc
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── notifications
│   │   │       └── live-test.js
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── test_live.html
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── utils.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── registeration
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20160211_1250.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20160211_1250.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_event_participants.py
│   │   ├── 0003_event_participants.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │   ├── bootstrap-fluid-adj.css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── bootstrap-responsive.css
│   │   └── bootstrap-responsive.min.css
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings.png
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-white.png
│   │   └── twd.ico
│   └── js
│       ├── bootstrap.js
│       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│       ├── jquery-2.0.3.js
│       ├── jquery-2.0.3.min.js
│       └── rango-ajax.js
└── templates
    └── registeration
        ├── base.html
        ├── events.html
        ├── index.html
        ├── login.html
        ├── profile.html
        └── register.html
```

I have followed all the instructions but I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [django-chance](https://github.com/benliles/django-chance) app you are using has not been updated in several years, and does not appear to support Django 1.9. You can either use a different app instead, or try to update it to work with Django 1.9.

This part of the traceback shows that it imports `signals.py` in the `__init__.py`, which tries to import models before the apps are loaded.

```
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/Event-Management-System/chance/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chance import signals
  File "/home/bewithaman/Projects/Event-Management-System/chance/signals.py", line 7, in <module>
    from chance.models import Registration
```

Remove this line from your `chance/__init__.py` file

```
from chance import signals
```

Then create an `change/apps.py` file, and define an app config class that imports the signals in the `ready()` method.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ChanceConfig(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

Finally, update your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting to use your config.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'chance.apps.ChanceConfig',
    ...
]
```