# Error when updating from django 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: django, django-paypal

I have a website running django 1.7.4 and i am trying to upgrade to django 1.9.5:

When I run `./manage.py runserver` I get:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x111306c80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/myuser/projects/mysite/myapp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import signals
  File "/Users/myuser/projects/mysite/myapp/signals.py", line 1, in <module>
    from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/standard/models.py", line 44, in <module>
    class PayPalStandardBase(Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I have django 1.7.4 installed in a virtualenv and with that version everything works fine. When i try to run it using django 1.9 this errors comes up. Any ideas?

(I have already tried to add `django.setup()` to `settings.py` as suggested in other answers, but it did not help (and reading the docs i feel it should not be there anyways)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to move the signal registration from your app's `__init__` method into the `ready()` method. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797839/django-1-9-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet/35798074#35798074) for an example.

Comment: This is a duplicate, there are a lot of posts about this error when upgrading. Also, you should not skip 1.8 when upgrading. You will miss some warnings etc.

Comment: @Lucas03 I've check that answer before posting, and it does not apply to my case. I will now try Alasdair suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: @Alasdair: Thank you, that solved the problem!

Comment: @pnjun glad it helped :)